# Custom NavigationLink working in local ContentView but invisible in Main one

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I was trying to create a custom NavigationLink so I could change its look and also use it repeatedly like in the calling (second) code snippet.

I have defined the custom NavigationLink like this:

```
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: linkDestination,
                isActive: $isPressed,
                label: {
                    Button(action: {
                        isPressed = true
                    }) {
                        VStack {
                            Label(labelName, systemImage: icon)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .fill(color)
                        )
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(CustomNavigationButtonStyle(isActive: isPressed))
                }
            )
        }
```

It works and is visible in the ContentView in the same file as the view declaration but they're both invisible when calling it like the below. Obviously it's different but I can't see anything that would hide them or make them invalid in some way.

I'm calling it twice below.

Sorry in advance for not having full code snippets. It wouldn't let me post more without fluffing the non-code text:

```
...
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                AppBar(title: "Votion")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 44)
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                            .padding(40.0)
                        Text("Create Task")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding()
                        CustomNavLink(
                            labelName: "Personal",
                            icon: "person",
                            linkDestination: PersonalTaskForm())
                        CustomNavLink(
                            labelName: "Business",
                            icon: "laptopcomputer.and.iphone",
                            linkDestination: PersonalTaskForm())
                    }
                }
            }
...
```

Can you see any reason why both CustomNavLinks wouldn't be visible?

Comment: NavigationLink with is active isn’t designed to work with the new NavigationStack. Also, in most applications you only need 1 NavigationStack at the very top it looks like you are creating one for each link

Comment: It does though, as I said in the post.